# How to send DSCP-marked packets using iperf?

Tags: networking, network-traffic

How to send [DSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiated_services)-marked packets using iperf?

I did not find the option in 1.7.0 version on Windows. Are there any newer versions of iperf for Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby's packgen is good .

Answer (score 10):

You have to run iperf with '-S' option:

`iperf -c 10.19.4.10 -i 1 -u -b 5000K -r -S 0xB8`

You can get your tos value here:

http://www.tucny.com/Home/dscp-tos

Answer (score 1):

[This posting](http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/lists/iperf-users/feb03/msg00015.html) explains how to enable DSCP in iperf. It's from 2003, so it should be in recent releases, I guess.